# Solve congruence $8x \equiv 28 \mod30 , 11x \equiv 1 \mod35$

Tags: congruences, chinese-remainder-theorem

I need to solve the following set of congruences.

\begin{cases} 8x \equiv 28 & \mod30 \\
11x \equiv 1 & \mod35\end{cases}

Finding the inverse of $11$ in the ring $\mathbb{Z}_{35}$ led to this simplification.

\begin{cases} 8x \equiv 28 & \mod30 \\
x \equiv 16 & \mod35\end{cases}

So we have:
$$30m+28=8x=8(35*n+16)=280n+128$$
$$30m-280n=100$$

Now $30\cdot(-9)+280=10$ so could possibly be $m=-90$ and $n=10$.

So $x=350+16=366$.

But $366$ doesn't fit the bill.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Notice that $30$ and $35$ are not relatively prime.  Then, you need to check each prime modulo congruence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather: "... so $m=-90$ and $n=-10$".

Comment: Ahh, yes, stupid mistake on my part as per tradition. But are $-334+30\cdot35\cdot k$ where $k \in \mathbb{N}$ the only solutions for this?